# How to pass long in logstash avro plugin?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, logstash, avro

I'm using logstash avro plugin.

My client is a java application. I have few schemas that use 'long' as a type and each time when I send them I see wrong value after deserialization. I suppose that there's some overflow in logstash avro plugin. 
Is there any workarounds for it? I don't want to send string each time when i have big value...

Here's the code snippets for my case. I have a valid .avsc schema with such field:

```
{
  "name": "scoringId",
  "type": "long",
},
```

And then i have avro-generated DTO on java side, which i convert to ByteArray.
 My kafka config is ok, it uses ByteArraySerializer:

```
props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, ByteArraySerializer::class.java)
```

In logstash conf i have such input:

```
input {
  kafka {
    bootstrap_servers => 'kafkaserver:9092'
    topics => ["bart.vector"]
    codec => avro { schema_uri => "C:\logstash-6.1.2\vectorInfoDWH.avsc" }
    client_id => "logstash-vector-tracking"
  }
}
```

It uses avro plugin. And as a result i can access all of the fields and get correct values except longs(and timestamps, because they're translated as longs).

Any ideas?

Comment: Please share relevant code snippet

Comment: I've found that in ruby avro codec implementation ints and longs are parsed in the same way:
http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/avro-jruby/1.7.5/Avro/IO/BinaryDecoder#read_int-instance_method

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with serializationDeserialization. Convertion of message to base64 from java side was a solution.